# In React native Web - "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

In React native Web - "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"

```
ERROR
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\MyWork\RND\app_new_source-fix\node_modules\react-native-screens\src\screens.web.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (105:12):

  103 |
  104 |   render() {
> 105 |     return <Animated.View {...this.props} ref={this._setRef} />;
      |            ^
  106 |   }
  107 | }
  108 |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PhgC.png)

```
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-content-loader": "6.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
...
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^v7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.7.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~18.2.0"
```

Geting error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjMQ2.png)

anyother way fix for this issue ?